# GWTP Protecting against XSRF attacks

Tags: gwt, tomcat, gwt-platform

I am developing a web application with GWT and GWTP. I look into the [wiki page of GWTP](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-platform/wiki/GettingStartedDispatch) and do the protection against XSRF attacks follow the instruction. It runs ok in the Dev mode.

Now I deployed it to the Tomcat Server. But in the console, it keeps telling me no cookie sent by client in RPC. And the result is no RPC call is able to execute as it is considered to be a XSRF attack.

Could anyone tell me what's wrong with it? Is it because of the Tomcat setting, since the app runs ok in Dev mode.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not from GWTP, it's something related to your Tomcat

> The session and SSO cookies in Tomcat 7 are being sent with HttpOnly flag by default, to instruct browsers to prevent access to those cookies from JavaScript. (This can be enabled in Tomcat 6.0 and 5.5 by setting useHttpOnly="true" on Context element in a web application or in the global CATALINA_BASE/conf/context.xml file). 
>   http://tomcat.apache.org/migration.html#Session_cookie_configuration

So, check your context.xml whether something like this:

```
  <Context cookies="true" useHttpOnly="false" >
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
    </Context>
```

> Should the HttpOnly flag be set on session cookies to prevent client
>   side script from accessing the session ID? Defaults to true.

More about [Context Attributes](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html#Attributes)